# Collapse all layer styles at once with Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm looking for a way to collapse all layer styles at once using Photoshop.

When I say "layer styles", I mean the list under the layer of all the styles that a layer has.

I know you can click the arrow beside `FX` to collapse a single layer's style, and holding `Ctrl` while clicking this button does not collapse all of the styles at once like it does with the layer groups.

Comment: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1081961?tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion is to select all the layers you have in your photoshop document and put them in a group, then **press  Alt** next to the inverted triangle that is situated next to the layer styles icon  to expand or collapse all of the layer styles applied within a group.

Comment: nope. didnt work. already tried it.

Comment: i found it on adobe help forum and it works on my version of photoshop: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop/11.0/WS8AA50342-7B58-4ef1-A0FC-F7D96A2271B1a.html